# How can I allow my Android app to be found on device's Home Screen search with custom strings?

Tags: android, search, homescreen

I have an application called "My Application", let's say this is a mail application. Then when the user searches in device's Home Screen search (for example Samsung's One UI Home Finder), I would like for searches like "email", "message", etc to show my app among those results, even though those search strings are not in the app's name. For example in the case of Samsung I can find GMail or Outlook just by typing "send", "email" and probably more words.

What I have tried so far:

1. Change the label of the launcher  element in the AndroidManifest.xml file to include some of the search strings. For example, change from "My Application" to "My mail messages", the problem is that I can only add a few search terms here (launcher name would be too long).
2. Add  elements to AndroidManifest.xml file, all of them targetting the launcher . This is not good because I get many app icons on the Home Screen instead of just one.
3. Add shortcuts meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml inside the launcher  element and declare several shortcuts in a xml file targetting the same launcher Activity. This shows a shortcut for each search string I want to find my app, but it is not an elegant solution when the user performs long click on the app's icon. Also this only works on some devices and it does not work on other ones. See in the image below how this looks on a Huawei for example.

[image: example of using several shortcuts]

Thanks in advance, I keep investigating about this, appreciate your help :)